# What is the type of a Transposed Range when passed as a parameter in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a User Defined Function 'HP' which I use in Excel using VBA (not VB.NET). It takes a Range parameter:

```
Function HP(data as Range)
```

It is designed to work for data that is organised 'vertically' - typically with one column being a series containing multiple observations. Each cell in the column is an observation

Thus, the function works with a range (for example) like this:

```
=HP(D1:D100)
```

I need to adapt it to function with data organised 'horizontally' - typically a single row.

In my spreadsheet, I enter the following

```
=HP(Transpose(A1:CV1))
```

This returns a #VALUE error. On examination, it seems that there is a type error: it does not accept `TRANSPOSE(A1:CV100)` as a Range object

A similar trick used to work, a couple of years ago. Now it doesn't.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share the code of the function?

Comment: Depending on your code, the range will be interpreted as either a range object, a 2-D variant array, or a 1-D variant array.